# Close - Off topic pop up?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, vote-to-close

I've noticed on some questions when I click close and off topic I sometimes get no option to select another SE site to move the post to. Is there a reason why some questions let me select a SE site and other times there's no other options?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Aarthi but why has it appeared then for me once in a while?

Comment: Hmm, unsure. The next time it happens, could you grab a screencapture? That would help us figure out the problem better!

Comment: Yes I will do that

Comment: Added a screen shot of one question which has migration options

Comment: I think I've figured it out AND updated my answer! I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** I'm <strike>wholesale theiving</strike> *adapting* this from [a similar post on Unix and Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/137/12872).

For 3k users: **Only if migration paths are enabled.**

Migrating between sites has been supported in the engine for [a while now](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/), but is currently only enabled for graduated sites. This is the off-topic close dialog here:

[image: webmasters]

Most sites (read: betas) have a similar dialog, but the only option is a one-directional migration from the main site to meta:

[image: robots]

For ♦ mods: **Yes**.

Moderators can basically migrate a post to anywhere.

**In your case:** Sounds like the posts you're wanting to migrate [are older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days):

> Therefore, I think the real solution is much simpler: just disable the migration of old questions. They're rarely welcomed or heavily improved post-migration, often overtly disliked by folks on the destination site, and can end up causing a rather bad experience for folks who were participating in good faith on the original.
>
> I suggest that questions older than 60<sup>1</sup> days should not be eligible for migration, either by normal user close-votes or by moderators. In extreme cases, we can perhaps provide an alternate means of moving old questions, but under normal circumstances these should be done quickly or not at all.
>
> <sup>1</sup> <sub>60 days is actually based on a rather unfortunate side-effect of the rep-retention changes introduced this past spring: migrated and then rejected questions older than 60 days cause the authors to suddenly gain (permanent) reputation on the destination.</sub>